# How to delete a quality profile in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Does anybody know how to delete a quality profile in SonarQube?

I am trying to suppress the unused javascript quality profile "Sonar way" :

[image]

I am administrator and clicking the down arrow, I only have the following options :

- Compare
- Copy
- Set as default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not delete a default or built-in quality profile. Otherwise, you would see that option in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the outdated copy name you can simply rename it yourself using the "rename" function in the drop down. The drop down will give you the option to fully delete this outdated copy if you you make the "Built-in" profile or one of your own profiles the default one.